# What happens if x86 jmp jumps to an address between two other consecutive valid ones?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

In a routine in x86 assembly, what happens if the code contains a jump that points to a valid address in between two valid addresses? Here is an artificial example:

```
0x0001: mov ...
0x0005: add ... 
0x0009: jmp 0x0003
```

Besides, how can I experiment with something like this on a local machine or online? I checked the online x86 editor like https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly, but it does not allow me to put the instruction addresses like "0x0001".

Comment: `jmp label+2` or `label-1` should assemble fine in most assemblers.  Or `jmp .-8` (GAS) or `jmp $-8` (NASM) to jump relative to the *start* of the `jmp` instruction.  (Not setting the `rel8` machine code encoding directly, the assembler still calculates that relative to the end of the instruction because that's how x86 machine code works.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “valid” or an “invalid” address.  Every address can be jumped to and if the corresponding page is mapped, executed.

So what happens when you jump “between” instructions?  Well, the processor does not know where you intend instructions to begin and end.  It just executes the bytes it sees.  This code will be different from what you expect because the CPU tries to parse the middle of some other instruction as an opcode.

Your specific example is not sufficiently specified for me to say what instructions result.  Perhaps you can provide a completely specified example (including the machine code) so I can give a better explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The CPU will start decoding instructions at the target address.

The instruction stream you are looking at in a disassembly (when using a tool like `objdump`) is merely one interpretation of the executable bytes of the program, assuming a given start point.

As it happens "jumping into the middle of an instruction" is an obfuscation technique sometimes used by malware to hide program semantics from linear sweep disassemblers (like `objdump`). More intricate disassemblers will make an attempt to follow these "misaligned" jumps, but it may not be possible, depending upon what can/can't be determined statically/dynamically.

The paper ["Obfuscation of executable code to improve resistance to static disassembly" by Linn and Debray](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/948109.948149) talks about this in more detail.

See Section 3.2 "Junk Insertion". The scenario you describe is what they refer to as "partially or fully overlapping instructions", i.e. different interpretations of the byte stream can give different assembly instructions for overlapping address ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I recently added a trick to codegolf's "Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code" about [skipping instructions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/235553#235553). You'll find that those are an intentional application of jumping into part of a prior instruction. And not only for obfuscation. Here's the text of that answer in full:

## Skipping instructions

Skipping instructions are opcode fragments that combine with one or more subsequent opcodes. The subsequent opcodes can be used with a different entrypoint than the prepended skipping instruction. Using a skipping instruction instead of an unconditional short jump can save code space, be faster, and set up incidental state such as `NC` (No Carry).

My examples are all for 16-bit Real/Virtual 86 Mode, but a lot of these techniques can be used similarly in 16-bit Protected Mode, or 32- or 64-bit modes.

Quoting [from my ACEGALS guide](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/acegals.htm#skipping):

> ### 11: Skipping instructions
>
> The constants __TEST_IMM8, __TEST_IMM16, and __TEST_OFS16_IMM8 are defined to the respective byte strings for these instructions. They can be used to skip subsequent instructions that fit into the following 1, 2, or 3 bytes. However, note that they modify the flags register, including always setting NC. The 16-bit offset plus 16-bit immediate test instruction is not included for these purposes because it might access a word at offset 0FFFFh in a segment. Also, the __TEST_OFS16_IMM8 as provided should only be used in 86M, to avoid accessing data beyond a segment limit. After the db instruction using one of these constants, a parenthetical remark should list which instructions are skipped.

The 86 Mode defines [in lmacros1.mac 323cc150061e (2021-08-29 21:45:54 +0200)](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/323cc150061e/lmacros1.mac#l246):

```
%define __TEST_IMM8 0A8h                        ; changes flags, NC
%define __TEST_IMM16 0A9h                       ; changes flags, NC
                                        ; Longer NOPs require two bytes, like a short jump does.
                                        ; However they execute faster than unconditional jumps.
                                        ; This one reads random data in the stack segment.
                                        ;  (Search for better ones.)
%define __TEST_OFS16_IMM8 0F6h,86h              ; changes flags, NC
```

The `0F6h,86h` opcode in 16-bit modes is a `test byte [bp + disp16], imm8` instruction. I believe I am not using this one anywhere actually. (A stack memory access might actually be slower than an unconditional short jump, in fact.)

`0A8h` is the opcode for `test al, imm8` in any mode. The `0A9h` opcode changes to an instruction of the form `test eax, imm32` in 32- and 64-bit modes.

Two use cases [in ldosboot boot32.asm 07f4ba0ef8cd (2021-09-10 22:45:32 +0200)](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldosboot/file/07f4ba0ef8cd/boot32.asm):

First, chain two different entrypoints for a common function which both need to initialise a byte-sized register. The `mov al, X` instructions take 2 bytes each, so `__TEST_IMM16` can be used to skip one such instruction. (This pattern can be repeated if there are more than two entrypoints.)

```
error_fsiboot:
        mov al,'I'

        db __TEST_IMM16 ; (skip mov)
read_sector.err:
        mov al, 'R'     ; Disk 'R'ead error

error:
```

Second, a certain entrypoint that needs two bytes worth of additional teardown but can otherwise be shared with the fallthrough case of a later code part.

```
                mov bx, [VAR(para_per_sector)]
                sub word [VAR(paras_left)], bx
                jbe @F          ; read enough -->

                loop @BB
                pop bx
                pop cx

                call clust_next
                jnc next_load_cluster
                inc ax
                inc ax
                test al, 8      ; set in 0FFF_FFF8h--0FFF_FFFFh,
                                ;  clear in 0, 1, and 0FFF_FFF7h
                jz fsiboot_error_badchain
                db __TEST_IMM16
@@:
                pop bx
                pop cx
                call check_enough
                jmp near word [VAR(fsiboot_table.success)]
```

Here's a use case [in inicomp lz4.asm 4d568330924c (2021-09-03 16:59:42 +0200)](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/inicomp/file/4d568330924c/lz4.asm#l491) where we depend on the `test al, X` instruction clearing the Carry Flag:

```
.success:
        db __TEST_IMM8                  ; (NC)
.error:
        stc
        retn
```

Finally, here's a very similar use of a skipping instruction in [DOSLFN Version 0.41c (11/2012)](http://adoxa.altervista.org/doslfn/). Instead of `test ax, imm16` they're using `mov cx, imm16` which has no effect on the status flags but clobbers the `cx` register instead. (Opcode `0B9h` is `mov ecx, imm32` in non-16-bit modes, and writes to the full `ecx` or `rcx` register.)

```
;THROW-Geschichten... [english: THROW stories...]
SetErr18:
        mov     al,18
        db      0B9h            ;mov cx,nnnn
SetErr5:
        mov     al,5
        db      0B9h            ;mov cx,nnnn
SetErr3:
        mov     al,3
        db      0B9h            ;mov cx,nnnn
SetErr2:
        mov     al,2
SetError:
```